# Best approach to show and insert nested data

Tags: usability, forms

I have 2 tables, one is **company** and the other is **salesperson**. The requirement is that "one company can have many salespeople. Also a company and salesperson can have many phones"

I have a datatable to show companies, I was thinking to show salespeople in a popup datatable as well. I also have a new button to open forms to store data for nested insert.

[image]

I'm using tabs to insert companies and providers associated with it. I am using a list to record several phones for the company.

[image]

In the **Salesperson** tab I am adding each salesperson to a list. Also, each salesperson can have many phones so I am adding those phones to  another list. I think this is a little confusing.

Is this approach correct or can I improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution of your problem. If you find any doubt then comment.I will explain you.
You can apply same approach as "Add Salesperson" to add multiple phone number of the company.

[image]